# N reduce rounds in MapReducer

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I am working with Map/Reduce algorithm where I am trying to merge two or more trees in single reducer (will try to fine-tune amount of trees that are merged in one reducer later). I am trying to implement this algorithm using N reducer rounds.

I have tried solve this problem using ChainReducer, but it allows to define only one reducer (I'd probably would be able to achieve in creating that chain using loop). Moreover, I would like to define custom logic to specify when to emit the result.
Here's diagram of my algorithm architecture:

[image: Tree merging in MapReduce]

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of job control where in you can execute a number of map reduce jobs in  a sequence. In your case there are three phases in reducers and only one in mappers. You can have three map reduce jobs and for the jobs where you need only the reducer action you can make use of identity mappers.